# parse json from sharepoint?

Tags: java, json

I have a response received from sharepoint.

```
{
    "d": {
        "query": {
            "SecondaryQueryResults": {
                "__metadata": {
                    "type": "Collection(Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.REST.QueryResult)"
                },
                "results": []
            },
            "SpellingSuggestion": "",
            "TriggeredRules": {
                "__metadata": {
                    "type": "Collection(Edm.Guid)"
                },
                "results": ["e0205660-4971-4574-aa40-af6b4383cadd"]
            },
            "ElapsedTime": 224,
            "__metadata": {
                "type": "Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.REST.SearchResult"
            },
            "Properties": {
                "__metadata": {
                    "type": "Collection(SP.KeyValue)"
                },
                "results": [{
                    "ValueType": "Edm.Int32",
                    "Value": "10",
                    "Key": "RowLimit"
                }, {
                    "ValueType": "Edm.Guid",
                    "Value": "8413cd39-2156-4e00-b54d-11efd9abdb49",
                    "Key": "SourceId"
                }, {
                    "ValueType": "Edm.Guid",
                    "Value": "7bc4ba9e-80ff-7000-58cf-f7ac556d1e34",
                    "Key": "CorrelationId"
                }, {
                    "ValueType": "Edm.Boolean",
                    "Value": "false",
                    "Key": "WasGroupRestricted"
                }, {
                    "ValueType": "Edm.Boolean",
                    "Value": "false",
                    "Key": "IsPartial"
                }, {
                    "ValueType": "Edm.Boolean",
                    "Value": "false",
                    "Key": "HasParseException"
                }, {
                    "ValueType": "Edm.String",
                    "Value": "en",
                    "Key": "WordBreakerLanguage"
                }, {
                    "ValueType": "Edm.Boolean",
                    "Value": "false",
                    "Key": "IsPartialUpnDocIdMapping"
                }, {
                    "ValueType": "Edm.Boolean",
                    "Value": "true",
                    "Key": "EnableInterleaving"
                }, {
                    "ValueType": "Edm.Boolean",
                    "Value": "false",
                    "Key": "IsMissingUnifiedGroups"
                }, {
                    "ValueType": "Edm.String",
                    "Value": "i62456",
                    "Key": "Constellation"
                }, {
                    "ValueType": "Edm.String",
                    "Value": "<Query Culture=\"en-US\" EnableStemming=\"True\" EnablePhonetic=\"False\" EnableNicknames=\"False\" IgnoreAllNoiseQuery=\"True\" SummaryLength=\"180\" MaxSnippetLength=\"180\" DesiredSnippetLength=\"90\" KeywordInclusion=\"0\" QueryText=\"59055305\" QueryTemplate=\"\" TrimDuplicates=\"True\" Site=\"e297bd2b-597a-4f54-8509-e2febb91b869\" Web=\"d42ff0d1-883b-4545-ab6a-97b0401025d4\" KeywordType=\"True\" HiddenConstraints=\"\" \/>",
                    "Key": "SerializedQuery"
                }]
            },
            "PrimaryQueryResult": {
                "RefinementResults": null,
                "SpecialTermResults": null,
                "QueryId": "0585a5f1-89bc-43c1-b736-e163b4d7c1dd",
                "QueryRuleId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "CustomResults": {
                    "__metadata": {
                        "type": "Collection(Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.REST.CustomResult)"
                    },
                    "results": []
                },
                "__metadata": {
                    "type": "Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.REST.QueryResult"
                },
                "RelevantResults": {
                    "Table": {
                        "__metadata": {
                            "type": "SP.SimpleDataTable"
                        },
                        "Rows": {
                            "results": [{
                                "__metadata": {
                                    "type": "SP.SimpleDataRow"
                                },
                                "Cells": {
                                    "results": [{
                                        "ValueType": "Edm.Double",
                                        "Value": "26.8860855102549",
                                        "__metadata": {
                                            "type": "SP.KeyValue"
                                        },
                                        "Key": "Rank"
                                    }, {
                                        "ValueType": "Edm.Int64",
                                        "Value": "17594532057853",
                                        "__metadata": {
                                            "type": "SP.KeyValue"
                                        },
                                        "Key": "DocId"
                                    }, {
                                        "ValueType": "Edm.Int64",
                                        "Value": "17594531057253",
                                        "__metadata": {
                                            "type": "SP.KeyValue"
                                        },
                                        "Key": "WorkId"
                                    }, {
                                        "ValueType": "Edm.String",
                                        "Value": "Customer Request Filling",
                                        "__metadata": {
                                            "type": "SP.KeyValue"
                                        },
                                        "Key": "Title"
                                    }, {
                                        "ValueType": "Edm.String",
                                        "Value": "Technology Services;svc ECMWise",
                                        "__metadata": {
                                            "type": "SP.KeyValue"
                                        },
                                        "Key": "Author"
                                    }, {
                                        "ValueType": "Edm.Int64",
                                        "Value": "97182",
                                        "__metadata": {
                                            "type": "SP.KeyValue"
                                        },
                                        "Key": "Size"
                                    }, {
                                        "ValueType": "Edm.String",
                                        "Value": "https:\/\/xxxxxx.sharepoint.com\/sites\/news\/CUST\/Forms\/Appeals\/Customer Reader.pdf",
                                        "__metadata": {
                                            "type": "SP.KeyValue"
                                        },
                                        "Key": "Path"
                                    }, {
                                        "ValueType": "Null",
                                        "Value": null,
                                        "__metadata": {
                                            "type": "SP.KeyValue"
                                        },
    ....
```

What I am trying to get is the "Path" of "Value" string of that pdf as a snapshot from below (part of section from what was above)

```
{
          "ValueType": "Edm.String",
          "Value": "https:\/\/xxxxxx.sharepoint.com\/sites\/news\/CUST\/Forms\/Appeals\/Customer Reader.pdf",
          "__metadata": {
          "type": "SP.KeyValue"
          },
          "Key": "Path"
}
```

I have tried to use JSONObject to parse it like this.

```
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new InputStreamReader((httpConn.getInputStream())));      
            JSONObject folder = (JSONObject)jsonObject.get("d");    
            JSONObject query = (JSONObject) folder.get("query");
            JSONObject properties = (JSONObject) query.get("PrimaryQueryResult");
            JSONObject result = (JSONObject) properties.get("RelevantResults");
            JSONObject table = (JSONObject) result.get("Table");
            JSONObject rows = (JSONObject) table.get("Rows");
....
```

I was wondering if there is a easier way to do this or what if one of the key is not populated. It would throw null pointer exception so is there a way just to find a key directly inside of this long nested json and how do I get the field "Key" from the json array of the "Cells"

Comment: What JSON Library are you using?

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using a JSON serializer such as Jackson or GSON.

If the underlying JSON response structure will be the same for each call, even if it has missing keys, you can create your own POJO using something like [JSONSchema2POJO](https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/). This will generate a POJO with Jackson or GSON annotations using a JSON string that you provide. Here's an example using a snippet of your JSON string:

```
-----------------------------------com.example.Example.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Example {

@SerializedName("ValueType")
@Expose
private String valueType;
@SerializedName("Value")
@Expose
private String value;
@SerializedName("__metadata")
@Expose
private Metadata metadata;
@SerializedName("Key")
@Expose
private String key;

public String getValueType() {
return valueType;
}

public void setValueType(String valueType) {
this.valueType = valueType;
}

public String getValue() {
return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
this.value = value;
}

public Metadata getMetadata() {
return metadata;
}

public void setMetadata(Metadata metadata) {
this.metadata = metadata;
}

public String getKey() {
return key;
}

public void setKey(String key) {
this.key = key;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Metadata.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Metadata {

@SerializedName("type")
@Expose
private String type;

public String getType() {
return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
this.type = type;
}

}
```

This is standard practice when consuming JSON in Java and it allows keys/values to be null when the object is serialized without breaking your code.

If the JSON structure is completely unpredictable, GSON allows you to create [Generic types](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Generic-Types) or you can take it a step further and [write custom serializers](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization). Jackson likely has similar functionality but I'm only versed in GSON.

Answer (score 0):

You could use quick-json ([enter link description here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/quick-json/)) and have something like this (rapid version not optimized) :

```
public class Go {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        List<String> pdf_list = new ArrayList<>();

        JsonParserFactory factory= JsonParserFactory.getInstance();
        JSONParser parser=factory.newJsonParser();
        Map jsonMap=parser.parseJson("/54424034/sharepoint.json", "UTF-8");
        //jsonMap.get("d/query/PrimaryQueryResult/RelevantResults/Table/Rows/results");
        Map d = (Map) jsonMap.get("d");
        Map query = (Map) d.get("query");
        Map primaryQueryResult = (Map) query.get("PrimaryQueryResult");
        Map relevantResults = (Map) primaryQueryResult.get("RelevantResults");
        Map table = (Map) relevantResults.get("Table");
        Map rows = (Map) table.get("Rows");
        List<Map> results_rows = (ArrayList) rows.get("results");
        for (Map result_row : results_rows) {
            Map cells = (Map) result_row.get("Cells");
            List<Map> results_cells = (ArrayList) cells.get("results");
            for (Map result_cell : results_cells) {
                String key = (String) result_cell.get("Key");
                if ("Path".equalsIgnoreCase(key)) {
                    pdf_list.add((String) result_cell.get("Value"));
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(pdf_list);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

It just parses your Json and add all pdf path into a List